# Unit testing in Django with flexible url patterns

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-urls, dry, django-tests

I was using the following test to check whether page resolves to correct template:

```
from django.test import TestCase
class HomePageTest(TestCase):
    def test_landing_page_returns_correct_html(self):
        response = self.client.get('/')
        self.assertIn(member='Go to the', container=response.content.decode())

    def test_uses_test_home_template(self):
        response = self.client.get('/test/')
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response=response,
                                template_name='myapp/home.html')
```

I used many variations of `self.client.get('/test/')` or `self.client.get('/test/dashboard/')` etc. in many many tests. All of which are in my `myapp.urlpatterns`.

Then one day I decided to get rid of `/test/`. Or simply change the URL pattern. All of the tests failed because, well, I hardcoded the URLs.

I would like to use flexible URL's in my tests. I assume it involves something like:

```
from myapp.urls import urlpatterns as myapp_urls
```

and using `myapp_urls` throughout the tests.

I have two questions:

1. How can I implement it?
2. Will there be any (negative) side effects of this approach that I don't foresee?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reverse()`, for example if you've got something like this in your `urls.py`:

```
from news import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^archive/$', views.archive, name='news-archive')
]
```

you can write your test like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse

class NewsArchivePageTest(TestCase):
    def test_news_archive_page_does_something(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('news-archive'))
        # do some stuff with the response
```

Read more about `reverse()` in the  [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse). As for negative side effects I don't think there are any.

Comment: This worked great. I first added `from myapp.urls import urlpatterns as myapp_urls` to the preamble. Then I used `reverse('myapp_urls:test_view_url')`, where `test_view_url` is the name of the url pattern I used in `urlpatterns`. Thanks!